# Repeated regular expression match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that consists exclusively of numbers. I want to match groups of three of every digit excluding the first digit.

For example: `"1000123"` should return `"000"` and `"123"` as matches.

I tried using

```
/\d(\d{3})+/
```

but it only matches the first group being `"000"` and the global flag didn’t help either.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Does the string _only_ contain numbers?

Comment: Also, what language are you using the RegEx in?

Comment: Different languages has different regex options. Also different regex functions. There is no sure way of writing a regex which will work everywhere for what you want.

Comment: yes it only contains numbers and i am using js/coffeescript

Comment: Are you sure that your RegEx matched `000`? For me `'1000123'.match(/\d(\d{3})+/)` returns `["1000123", "123"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead. For exactly 3 digits.

```
(?!^\d)\d{3}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sT4gL6/1)

**or**

From 1 upto 3 digits.

```
(?!^\d)\d{1,3}
```

Comment: Don't you want to capture the groups? i.e. (?!^\d)(\d{3})